# Plotting probability density function of normal distribution, but y goes above 1?

Tags: plot, latex, normal-distribution, pgfplots

I'm trying to plot the probability density function of various normal distributions in latex. All have a mean of 0 and the standard deviations are: 0.4339, 0.4931 and 0.3665.

I use this code:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}

\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\lstset{
    showstringspaces=false,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    basicstyle=\small,
    breaklines=true
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[h]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={
  mark=none,domain=-2:2,samples=50,smooth},
  xmin=-1.6,
  xmax=1.6,
  ymin=0,
  xtick={},
  %ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=auto
  ],
  \addplot {gauss(0, 0.4339)};
  \addplot {gauss(0, 0.4931)};
  \addplot {gauss(0, 0.3665)};
  \addlegendimage{empty legend}
  \addlegendentry{$x$}
  \addlegendentry{$y$}
  \addlegendentry{$z$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This results in the following picture:

[Latex output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrIDp.png)

You can see that the y axis goes up to ~1.1. This makes no sense, right? As its a probability it should be below 1. Additionally the integral of the function should have a sum of 1, as I understand it. Thus the values should be much lower in general.

What am I doing wrong, am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
```

into

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{exp(-((x-(#1))*((x-(#1)))/(2*(#2)*(#2)))/((#2)*sqrt(2*pi))}%
}
```

without using the power function `^2`, which actually calls `pow(#1,2)`, and using all the brackets: maybe your distribution still have this [bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31775/211707).